# Cant install Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Sometimes this error appears:

> It is not possible to install the visual studio installer. Enable the Windows Service "Windows Management Instrumentation" and try again.

Other times the installer opens and starts the process, but it loads infinitely

[image]

Comment: Start that service with command `sc start Winmgmt` or `net start Winmgmt`

Comment: Did you do what you were told to do? "Enable the Windows Service "Windows Management Instrumentation" and try again."

Comment: Look at MS official VS 2017 installation guide, make sure the service: Windows Management Instrumentation is running
Install Visual Studio 2017
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio

Comment: When I do this and restart the computer, the installation starts but never ends. Bug with windows 10 version: 1709?

Comment: @Alberto It's problem with your system. Check your system. I have installed the latest VS in Win Fall CU and works fine.

Comment: I've formated the machine with Win 10 version 1607 and everithing works fine. I'm still thinking the problem is version 1709 WIn 10 PRO